# transaction-isolation level is ignored in my.cnf

Tags: mysql, database-administration, mysql-8.0, transaction-isolation, my.cnf

I am using mysql 8.0.27 running on ubuntu 20.04. transaction-isolation level is ignored in my.cnf and runs in default transaction_isolation-REPEATABLE-READ, but I am able to change the transaction-isolation in runtime without any issue.

****Action Taken till now:****

1. Verified  only one my.cnf file exists on the system. Whatever changes I do on the file, it gets reflected (except transaction_isolation) when restarting mysql service.
2. Verified error log & changed log_error_verbosity to 3. No information related to transaction isolation recorded.
3. Tried the same my.cnf file in a different server(same MYSQL & OS version) and transaction_isolation value gets updated when service restart happens.
4. Runs in default sql_mode.

Any pointers would be helpful on this thread!

Comment: Have you checked that this "only one my.cnf file" is loaded during server start at all? Do you put this setting into correct ([mysqld]) section of the options file? Try to specify this setting in service command line - does it is applied? Check your client and connector settings and client options file if exists - maybe incorrect level is set during the connection establishing? Check General log for excess statements which alters this setting. Test does this setting value obtained from event procedure is one you need.

Comment: I enabled the general log and changed the port so that no user alter setting runs, but still it routes to default transaction isolation. I tried to query the settings use mysqladmin show variable and it gives the same result. No client options exists on the file.

Comment: Issue was fixed by run the  command.

SET PERSIST transaction_isolation='READ-COMMITTED';